# How to perform the JNDI lookup for any web application in Apache Felix, that is installed using PAX Web?

Tags: apache-felix, pax

Using Pax Web, the Web application is installed on Apache Felix.
Now, the web application needs to perform the JNDI Lookup.

In JNDI, the key prefix is "java:comp/env".

While trying the JNDI lookup, it gives the following error:

[javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial].

It seems the property 'java.naming.factory.initial' needs to be provided.

Question: What should be the value of 'java.naming.factory.initial' as it is being installed in Apache Felix ?

Any response will be highly appreciated.